# How to Make dynamic text in Adobe After Effects like in Adobe Flash Professional

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, after-effects

In adobe Flash proffesional we can make dynamic texts and give instance name and export in swf and we can use in Flex Builder swf loader and can dynamically get that instancce name and can change the Text. But Animations in Adobe After Effects are really cool. So is there any way i can do the same?
I mean can we make such animations in After Effects and Get the text objects from exported swf or some other thing???

I might not be able to explain my question well, But i really need some help.
Pls, I am a beginner so please go light on me iv asked before on Stack Overflow but people seem to turn me down by saying thats a stupid Question.

Comment: You can use script in after effects to change the value of a text layer.  Not sure about reading a swf though, that at any rate is much too broad to answer nicely here.

Comment: After Effects does not handle Actionscript code within any SWF (only shows graphics and animation frames). The best you can do is create an AE project and updated text layers from reading a saved text file. **[Here is a tutorial](http://www.provideocoalition.com/expression_shorts_-_read_external_text_document)**. Read it carefully. PS: If you got downvotes, maybe cos this is not seen as a real programming question.